# Load intro page before actual web-page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to load single `index.html` file before actual `index.php` I have on server.

I have:

`index.html` - (intro page)

`index.php` - (actual webpage index file)

```
.htaccess rewrite rule
```

Sounds simple, but .htaccess redirects every webpage query back to my index.html file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What is the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mod_rewrite, use [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) and give priority to index.html

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

**Note:** While this should work, I don't recommend it as it creates ambiguity. One of those configuration changes that will haunt you later.

Comment: I need to use these rewrites cause webpage's framework requires them. I must use them

Comment: Then keep them and add the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `DirectoryIndex` directive for that:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

**From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html):**

> The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for, when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a / at the end of the directory name. Local-url is the (%-encoded) URL of a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is usually the name of a file in the directory. Several URLs may be given, in which case the server will return the first one that it finds. If none of the resources exist and the Indexes option is set, the server will generate its own listing of the directory.

Comment: I understand that, but I must keep rewrites cause its a part of a actual webpage. Can I add additional rewrites conditions?

Comment: No idea of what to be written on this condition. Do you?